# Issues when toolbar and appbarLayout work with transparent navigation bar

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-appbarlayout

In my activity I have a list, I want my list under transparent navigation bar.

I define a Theme :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>
```

Here is my layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout_base"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        <!-- only for test -->
        <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/containerContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2000dp"
                    android:background="#FF00FF"/>

        </RelativeLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

But I got toolbar and appbar under status bar : [Toobar and Appbar layout under status bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyncO.png)

I try to add `fitSystem = "true"` to toolbar, I got some weired height of toolbar : [Wrong toolbar height](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcJA4.png)

Anyone how to know to fix this? Thanks a lot!

I use :

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
```